# Как зашифровать программу на С

Tags: c, пароль

Есть программа:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char pass[10] = {0};
    printf("Enter password ?");
    scanf("%s", pass);

    if(strcmp(pass, "zorg443") == 0)
    {
        printf("Success.\r\n");
    }

    else
    {
        printf("Bad password.\r\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Я сижу на kali linux. Пришла в голову идея окрыть a.out (на windows name.exe)
через bless hex editor (Читает 16-ый код), а в нем пароль прям выделяется. Как можно зашифровать его для защиты от такого?

Comment: использовать любой хеш?

Comment: вы можете воспользоваться UPX и код менять не надо :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы просто хотите, чтобы он не был виден в открытом виде? тогда можно просто вместо `zorg443` написать `ynqf332`, а потом, перед началом работы, увеличить каждый символ на 1 :)

Но можно хранить что-то иное - например, значение crc32, md5 или какого-то sha1 - вобщем, какого-то [дайджеста](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), а потом после ввода пользовательского пароля вычислять его же для этого ввода и сравнивать с вашим...

Comment: char pass[10] = {0};
    char mainPass[10] = {'y','n','q','f','3','3','2'};
    mainPass[0] =+ 1;
    printf ("%s\r\n", mainPass); Мне выводит какойто странный символ, почему следующий же z в ascii table?

Comment: Опишите действие оператора **=+**...

Comment: Это вы описали оператор инкремента **+=**, а не **=+**.

Comment: Аааа. Я понял))

Comment: Вы присвоили первому элементу массива значение `+1`. Переставили местами `+` и `=`...

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Да не за что :)

Answer (score 1):

То что получилось:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
char pass[20] = {0};
char mainPass[20] = {"ynqf332"};

for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    mainPass[i] += 1;
}

printf("Enter password ?");
scanf("%20s", pass);

if(strcmp(mainPass, pass) == 0)
{
    printf("Success.\r\n");
}
else
{
    printf("Bad password.\r\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```